# Error when freeing buffer

Tags: c, winapi

My code:

```
wchar_t buffer[64];

wsprintf(buffer, L"%d, %d, %d", x, y, z);
SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buffer);

free(buffer); // <-- crashes
```

The code works fine when NOT freeing the buffer, however crashes when free(buffer) is used.

Is this line necessary, if not, why not? Isn't there a need to free memory after it's used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buffer` is allocated on stack, not on the heap, you don't need to `free` it by yourself.

If `buffer` is created dynamically using `malloc` (in C) or `new` (in C++), you need `free` (in C) or `delete` (in C++). Dynamic arrays are created on the heap. static arrays (size known at compile time) are allocated on stack.

Comment: I see, so when should i free a buffer? How do I know if the buffer is allocated on stack or not?

Comment: @ChaseTheSun If you _explicitly_ allocates the buffer, with e.g. `malloc` or similar function, then you need to free it. Variables on the stack are handled completely by the compiler.

Comment: Which is, of course, why you should always prefer this approach whenever possible: it prevents memory leaks and offloads tedious work to the compiler.

Comment: this is all well and good, except he doesn't know what you mean by on the stack, most likely.  Especially since the C standard doesn't even require the implementation to use one.